# Java script from hover to onclick

Tags: javascript

How can I change this script from hover to onclick:

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    $j(".swatch-anchor").hover(function() {
        var newTitle = $j(this).attr("title");
        $j("#colour-name").html(newTitle);
    },
    function() {
        var swapTitle = $j("#colour-name").html();
        $j(this).attr("title",swapTitle);
        $j("#colour-name").html("");
    });
});
```

someone suggested changing .hover to .click and that just does not work.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: Change the `.hover(` to `.click(`?

Comment: like i said above that just does not work

Answer (score 1):

Well,

this should work:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j(".swatch-anchor").on('click',function () {
        var newTitle = $j(this).attr("title");
        $j("#colour-name").html(newTitle);
    });
});
```

but you loose this code that was executed on mouse leave because jQuery's [**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) has a  `handlerOut` optional function that `click` does not.

```
var swapTitle = $j("#colour-name").html();
$j(this).attr("title",swapTitle);
$j("#colour-name").html("");
```

**EDIT:**

An attempt to combine both mouse hover and click:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j(".swatch-anchor").on('click mouseenter',function () {
        var newTitle = $j(this).attr("title");
        $j("#colour-name").html(newTitle);
    });

    $j(".swatch-anchor").on('mouseleave',function () {
       var swapTitle = $j("#colour-name").html();
        $j("#colour-name").html("");
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the down fall for loosing that bit of code?

Comment: is there a way to have hover and onclick work at the same time?

Comment: @anmaree, the "down fall" is important or not depending on what you want to do in your page. You can separate the functions and use `.on('click mouseenter', function(){...` with the first part of the code and another one just for `.on('mouseleave', function() { etc` with the second part of the code.

Comment: your talking about the first and second part of the original code correct? would you mind writing it out for me because the second part of the code is a little confusing to me

Comment: like this:     `$j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    $j(".swatch-anchor").on("click", function() {
        var newTitle = $j(this).attr("title");
        $j("#colour-name").html(newTitle);
    },
    .on('mouseleave', function() { {
        var swapTitle = $j("#colour-name").html();
        $j(this).attr("title",swapTitle);
        $j("#colour-name").html("");
    });
});`

Comment: @anmaree, just updated my answer. Check the EDIT

Comment: thank you... with that code it only really works on hover: {http://www.annarbortees.com/product/gildan-5000-4/}

Comment: @anmaree, that is why it's not possible to replace hover with click. What is the functionality you are missing?

Comment: I am going to start a new thread regarding combining hover and onclick with the code original code in question.

Comment: @anmaree, can you explain what is not working now?

Comment: I implemented your "attempt to combine both mouse hover and click" code and the code works when the window load because there is a selection on load, but once I hover another element, it does not work on click. if you can not understand what I am saying see the link {http://www.annarbortees.com/product/gildan-5000-4/} for an example

Comment: @anmaree, I saw your link. What is not working? Is it when hovering the colors?

Comment: the hover works, but I also want to be able to click those colors and have them hold the title there on click, but then also hover the other images and see their titles

Comment: @anmaree, then you don't need the `mouseleave` part. The mouseleave part is the one clearing the name of the color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $j=jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() { 
       $j(".swatch-anchor").on("click", function() {
          var newTitle = $j(this).attr("title");
          $j("#colour-name").html(newTitle);
       });
    });
```